# If $S_k = \sum ^{\infty}_{i=0} \frac{1}{(k+1)^i}$ then the value of $\sum ^{n}_{k=1} k.S_k$ is

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$S_k=\frac{1}{k+1} + \frac{1}{(k+1)^2}+ \frac{1}{(k+1)^3}.......\infty$$

I don’t think we can find the sum of the infinite terms, as not enough data about k is given, but even I f try it 
$$S_k=\frac 1k$$

So putting it in the original summation would just given me n, but the right answer is $\frac{(n)(n+3)}{2}$. I don’t know how to get to that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

$$S_k=1+\frac{1}{k+1} + \frac{1}{(k+1)^2}+ \frac{1}{(k+1)^3}+\cdots\infty=\dfrac1{1-\dfrac1{k+1}}=\dfrac{k+1}k$$

$$k\cdot S_k=?$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk\cdot S_k=\sum_{k=1}^n(k+1)=?$$

Comment: Wow, completely forgot i=0. However, is it correct to assume that $-1<k+1<1$

Comment: @Aditya, Yes, I should have pointed out. $$S_k\ne\dfrac{k+1}k$$  unless  $$\left|\dfrac1{k+1}\right|<1$$

Comment: @Aditya,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum

Comment: I deleted it my comment before yours had updated. I got it.

Comment: Again, the condition for making it an infinite geometric progression isn’t given, so how can we just assume it